# How to find all gaps of a domain of a function with Mathematica 9?

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

I tried it liek this:

My test-function:

```
fuu[x_] := Expand[FullSimplify[1/x]]
```

how i find the domain:

```
domain[f_] := 
 Module[{}, 
  Reduce[Exists[{y}, Element[x, Reals] && y == f, Element[y, Reals]]]]
domain[fuu[x]]
(*x < 0 || x > 0*)
```

How i tried to find the gaps:

```
gaps[f_] := 
 Not[Reduce[
   Exists[{y}, Element[x, Reals] && y == f, Element[y, Reals]]]] 
gaps[fuu[x]]
(*! (x < 0 || x > 0)*)
```

How can i do it that he just says x == 0 ?

Comment: In v10: `FunctionDomain[1/x, x, Reals] // FullSimplify` `(* x != 0 *)`

Comment: I have Mathematica 9..

Comment: lol i just needed to Fullsimplify the last one..

Comment: sudo, rather than adding the answer to your question, would you mind posting it as an actual answer and in due time accepting it? That would make the question show up as answered, and it is encouraged on stackexchange to answer your own questions when you can.

Comment: @MarcoB thanks for taking the time to explain.. I am willing to learn :q

Answer (score 1):

```
gaps[f_] := 
     Not[Reduce[
       Exists[{y}, Element[x, Reals] && y == f, Element[y, Reals]]]] 
    gaps[fuu[x]] // FullSimplify
    (*x == 0*)
```

Comment: now i feel stupid and smart at the same moment :3 lol

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer (+1) And hey, you solved your problem, nothing to feel stupid about there! :-)